# BibLaTeX - Using new field as Labelname

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'd like to use the non-standard type jurisdiction with an optional field named officialvolume.

If set this field should be used for citation in the footnote. Jurisdication item don't have to apperar in the bibliography.

The declaration of the new fild can be found in the **myjura.dbx** file:

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal, label=true]{officialvolume}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{officialvolume}
```

Using DeclareLabelname I tried to achieve the citation by officialvalue in my **minimal.tex**:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,%
    autocite=footnote,%
    bibstyle=ext-authortitle,%
    citestyle=ext-authortitle,%
    datamodel=myjura,%
]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabelname[jurisdiction]{%
    \field{officialvolume}%
    \field{shortauthor}%
    \field{author}%
    \field{shorteditor}%
    \field{editor}%
    \field{translator}%
}

\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

\begin{document}
Cite\autocite{BGH1.Strafsenat.03.05.1960}
\end{document}
```

Here is the coresponding **bibfile.bib**:

```
@jurisdiction{BGH1.Strafsenat.03.05.1960,
 author = {{BGH 1. Strafsenat}},
 officialvolume = {Editor},
 date = {1960-05-03},
 title = {Wehrstrafrecht},
 pages = {269--279},
 volume = {14}
}
```

Running biber (after at least one latex run) I get no error but the following warning: "WARN - Labelname candidate 'officialvolume' is not a name field - skipping"

The citation was supposed to read "Editor[...]" but came out as "BGH 1. Strafsenat[...]".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As the warning says: Biber expects your choices for `labelname` to be name fields. If `officialvolume` is a name-like field (i.e. it generally contains people's names), then change the data model declaration of the field from `type=field, datatype=literal` to `type=list, datatype=name`. If `officialvolume` is an un-name-y field, then you can't use `labelname` here and need to rewrite the cite bibmacro to handle `@jurisdiction` entries differently.

Comment: That working for me. Thanks @moewe - Can I mark this topic as solved or something like that?

Comment: I posted an answer with the same contents as my comment above that you can accept by clicking on the checkmark icon on the top left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`biblatex` and Biber warnings are not always known for their helpfulness. But this time it is actually spot on: Biber expects your choices for `labelname` in `\DeclareLabelname` to be name fields.

If `officialvolume` is a name-like field (i.e. it generally contains people's names), then change the data model declaration of the field from `type=field, datatype=literal` to `type=list, datatype=name`.

E.g. (with both the `.dbx` and `.bib` file created inline with `filecontents` to make the document self-contained)

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{myjura.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list, datatype=name, label=true]{officialvolume}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{officialvolume}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-authortitle,
  autocite=footnote,
  datamodel=myjura,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabelname[jurisdiction]{%
  \field{officialvolume}%
  \field{shortauthor}%
  \field{author}%
  \field{shorteditor}%
  \field{editor}%
  \field{translator}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@jurisdiction{BGH1.Strafsenat.03.05.1960,
  author         = {{BGH 1.~Strafsenat}},
  officialvolume = {Editor},
  date           = {1960-05-03},
  title          = {Wehrstrafrecht},
  pages          = {269-279},
  volume         = {14},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Cite\autocite{BGH1.Strafsenat.03.05.1960}
\end{document}
```

[image: Editor, Wehrstrafrecht.]

If `officialvolume` is an un-name-y field, then you can't use `labelname` here and need to rewrite the relevant citation bibmacros to handle `@jurisdiction` entries differently.